# Two spinners in bokeh don't interact

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I'm trying to make an interactive normal distribution in Bokeh, where you can manipulate the values of mu and sigma to see how the graph is affected.

Both of my spinners work fine independently, but changing one resets the other. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

I'm not particularly adept in javascript. I tried at first to make this interactive plot using only Python, and it was successful. The problem is that it needs to be run on through bokeh using `bokeh serve ...` in my terminal.

I rewrote the code to use the JS callbacks so that I could save it as a standalone html file, but now I'm running into issues connecting all the parts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The code is posted below.

```py
import numpy as np

from scipy.stats import norm
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Spinner, Slider, TextInput, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file, save

# Set up data
sig = .5
mu = .1
x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.001)
y = norm.pdf(x, mu, sig)
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))


# Set up plot
plot = figure(height=400, width=400, title="Normal Distribution",
              tools="crosshair,pan,reset,save,wheel_zoom",
              x_range=[-2, 2], y_range=[0, 1])

plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

callbackmu = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, sig2=sig2), code="""
var data = source.data;
var input = cb_obj.value;
var s = sig2.value;

function fff (x, mu, sigma) {
    var num = Math.exp(-Math.pow((x - mu), 2) / (2 * Math.pow(sigma, 2)))
    var denom = sigma * Math.sqrt(2 * Math.PI)
    return num / denom
};

var a = input;

var x = data['x'];
var y = data['y'];

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    y[i] = fff (x[i], a, s);
}

source.change.emit();
""")

callbacksig = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, mu2=mu2), code="""
var data = source.data;
var input = cb_obj.value;
var m = mu2.value;
console.log(mu2)
function fff (x, mu, sigma) {
    var num = Math.exp(-Math.pow((x - mu), 2) / (2 * Math.pow(sigma, 2)))
    var denom = sigma * Math.sqrt(2 * Math.PI)
    return num / denom
};

var a = input;

var x = data['x'];
var y = data['y'];

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    y[i] = fff (x[i], m, a);
}

source.change.emit();
""")
 
mu2 = Spinner(title="mu", value=mu, low=-2.0, high=2.0, step=0.1)
mu2.js_on_change('value', callbackmu)

sig2 = Spinner(title='sig', value=sig, low=.01, high=1, step=.01)
sig2.js_on_change('value', callbacksig)

layout = column(mu2, sig2, plot)

show(layout)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a doofus.

I put the spinner assignments before the callback assignments and now everything works.